# How to read the JSON File using c# in pipeline

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-pipelines

I am trying to find solution for this problem.

Error:

```
Error when accessing database was 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\azagent\A2\_work\68\Automation\CommonLibSQL\databaseConfig.json'.
```

I have json file like this

```
      {
  "Dev": {
    "Studio": {
      "databaseServerName": "SqlServerName",
      "databaseName": "Studio",
      "databaseUser": "SqlUser",
      "databasePassword": "SqlPassword"
    }
  },
  "Test": {
    "Studio": {
      "databaseServerName": "SqlServerName",
      "databaseName": "Studio",
      "databaseUser": "SqlUser",
      "databasePassword": "SqlPassword"
    }
  },
  "SIT": {
    "Studio": {
      "databaseServerName": "SqlServerName",
      "databaseName": "Studio",
      "databaseUser": "SqlUser",
      "databasePassword": "SqlPassword"
    }
  }
}
```

and my code is below to read the file

```
string databaseConfigContents = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName, @"Automation\CommonLibSQL\databaseConfig.json"));
            var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(databaseConfigContents);
            settingsList.Add($"databaseConnectionString", new CommonSQLConnectorSettings
            {
                databaseServerName = CommonAppSettings.GetEnvironmentVariable(data[env][database]["databaseServerName"].Value<string>()),
                databaseName = CommonAppSettings.GetEnvironmentVariable(data[env][database]["databaseName"].Value<string>()),
                databaseUser = CommonAppSettings.GetEnvironmentVariable(data[env][database]["databaseUser"].Value<string>()),
                databasePassword = CommonAppSettings.GetEnvironmentVariable(data[env][database]["databasePassword"].Value<string>())
            });
```

I suspect something is wrong with this code

''' Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName
'''

above is working fine in LOcal but not in pipeline. Please help

Comment: What error occurs in pipeline? Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What image is the agent using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: Your path to the json files seems to try to break out of the working directory to go two levels up and then another path down (like escaping from bin/debug folder). Instead select the json file in Solution Explorer, right click - Properties and set to _Content_ and _Copy if newer_. Afterwards you can access the file relative from the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver I tried by changing the property and still its not working. I think something wrong in finding the path of file. 

Note:
i just changed the property alone to "Copy if newer".

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with this code

'''
Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName
'''

Comment: `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` does actually sound wrong to locate something you expect at a fixed location. The current directory is not something fixed or always points to your app.

Comment: Yes how to give relative path of json file to my code. so that it wont get failed in pipeline

Comment: This is fixed now. Thanks for all your comments